# Hide an Actionscript Error in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am using a component from an external library.  However whenever I use the component it says:

```
Error:  Error #2014: Feature is not available at this time.
```

The component works fine... and the bug has been reported.  But for now I want to try to hide this error.  In order to hide it I tried doing the following.

```
var myComp:MyComp = new myComp();
myComp.width = "100%";
myComp.height = "100%";

try {
  _page.myCompHBox.addChild(myComp);
} catch (e:Error) {}
```

_page is a reference to the .MXML page associated with the as3 class.

But it still didn't catch the error.  Any ideas / suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: what component are you using?

Comment: Yes it's important to know the component as well as if it fires an error on instantiation, or when you call some specific function? In order to get try-catch working, you should use it exactly when the error occurs - if you've used it on initialization and then try to call non existing method (for example) - it will still cause you trouble, as try-catch doesn't work for the whole component (class), but only for the operation that is inside it.

Comment: @AndreyPopov Unfortunately the component is private so I cannot get too much into detail about it.  However I have added a little bit about it in my OP.  The error is thrown when I try to add the component to my MXML.

Comment: @Zevan I cannot go into much detail about it because it is private.  However, I added a little bit that may be able to help.

Comment: If you cannot determine where to use the try/catch block, you can try using Flash's [global exception handler](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2009/10/global_error_handling_in_air_20.html).